# Should you scale through tables or computation in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a project with customers buying a product with platform based tokens. I have a mysql table that tracks a customer buying x amount and one tracking customer consumption(-x amount). In order to display their Amount of tokens they have left on the platform and query funds left on spending I wanted to query (buys - comsumed). But I remembered that people alsways talk about space is cheaper than computation(Not just $ but querytime as well). Should I have a seperate table for querying amount that gets updated with each buy or consume ?

So far I have always tried to use the least amount of tables to make it simple and have easy oversight, but I start to question if that is right...

Comment: Put your transactions (buying and consuming) in one transactions table. There is no benefit in splitting them, but it will likely add additional overhead. Unless individual users have millions of token transactions, getting current balance is trivial. If your transaction per user rate is expected to be very high you can implement some kind of statement period, whereby you periodically store a point-in-time balance. Then to get current balance you just need transactions since most recent statement balance.

Comment: [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [ask] [Help] Right now you are essentially asking us to (re)write a textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right answer, keep in mind the goal of the application, and updates in software likely to happen.

If you keep in these 2 tables transactions the user may have, then the new column was necessary, cause you had to sum the columns. If one row is for one user (likely your case), then 90% you should use those 2 tables only.

I would suggest you not have that extra column. As far with my expierence, in that kind of situations has the down of the bigger the project becomes, the more difficult is for you and the other developers, to have in mind to update the new column, because is **dependent variable**.
Also, when the user buy products or consumption tokens, you will have to update the new token, so energy and time loss as well.
You can **store** the (buys - consumed) **in session**, and update when is needed(if real time update is not necessary, not multiple devices).

If you need continuous update, so multiple queries over time, then memory loss over energy-time loss is greater, so you should have that 3 table - column.